# Url resolver problems - domains to wrong ip address

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, dns, virus, trojan

I have serious troubles with browsing :S

I have a new network with Cisco Linksys E1200 and a TP-LINK wireless adapter. My operation system is windows 7 ultimate 64bit. Nah my problem is, that when I type for example http://google.com or http://php.net then I get http://career-advice.monster.com/ instead of that :S by the http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php I get google 404 error... etc...
So my http requests are redirected to wrong servers....

There is another computer on this network, and I can browse with that very well, so the problem is with this computer not with the network settings (I think).

My computer is sometimes freezing for a half sec or so... (Haha maybe the virus sending my passwords :D fantastic...)

I have Eset Smart Security and downloaded F-Secure scanner too, but they found nothing. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Have you changed your HOSTS file? It's located at `%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: I have changed, but now I opened it, and there is a piece of ... created by adobe in that. Pff, I'll uninstall every adobe product, and try out after that, maybe it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't help, but I found a similar topic: http://www.computing.net/answers/security/system-hijacked/30836.html
The TDSS Killer found a thread... I deleted and now it seems working... Btw I have the freezings yet, so there are more hidden trojans on my computer I think. I'll reinstall the full system soon...

Comment: That's what you get when you pirate... If you fixed it, make sure you put it in an answer and mark it as such